# ISP whitelisting for mail server

Tags: isp, spam, whitelist

Is there any way to get the server whitelisted for all the ISP's?

Answer (score 5):

No. ISP's do their own thing, and many smaller ones change hands and configurations all the time.

Many ISP's end up wasting a lot of time tracking down and submitting requests with blackhole lists and RBL's and other larger ISP's trying to fight the effects of spam.

Even if there were a whitelist, it would mean they'd be vulnerable should you or one of your users become infected with an exploit and start spamming them.

Answer (score 1):

No. How should there be one? "ALL ISP" is like saying "heys, is there a list of all people that like pizza", world wide. There is no central registry of ISP to start with, so how can there be a way to get a server whitelisted to all ISP's?

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone else has said: No.

You can get yourself whitelisted with some of the big free email providers (Hotmail/Live & Yahoo definitely have procedures, I'm 99% sure Google does too, just search for their postmaster info on your favorite search engine), and you can talk to companies you do business with frequently to ensure that you can get through their filters, but there is no "universal whitelist" -- Such a service would be beseiged by spammers trying to get on it, making it both hideously expensive and enormously difficult to maintain it as a clean list.

Answer (score 0):

As the other replies have said there is no universal whitelist, @voretaq7 makes a good point with asking frequent contacts to whitelist you're domain name at their end to ensure mail gets through.

I'd advise asking your ISP to create a PTR record on the IP address that mail is being sent out over and I'd recommend heading over to http://mxtoolbox.com/ and creating an account and using their free monitoring tool to create a rule to check your mail server IP against their blacklist tool. This will alert you if you get caught up in a spam list and usually link you straight to the de-list request page.